# Allow troops to "shoot the hostages free"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idioms

I get stuck (and shocked) by the expression 'shoot the hostages free', in the following context from [Never Split the Difference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0062407805):

> But until the Nixon administration, hostage negotiating as a process was limited to sending in troops and trying to **shoot the hostages free**. In law enforcement, our approach was pretty much to talk until we figured out how to take them out with a gun. Brute force.

Does this mean that troops are allowed to shoot the hostages (direct object of *shoot*) without cost or at will?

My understanding is ridiculous and hence must be wrong. What does that mean then, especially the usage of 'free' here? Does this expression in that context seem misleading or confusing to native speakers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see how that could be confusing! But, as far as I can tell from the excerpt, "shoot the hostages free" doesn't mean the troops are shooting **at** the hostages, but instead that they're shooting at the *enemy soldiers* who are keeping the hostages prisoner. So, attempting to free the hostages by force: i.e. taking out their guards.  Like if they were tied up with rope, and the troops *cut* them free, that would be the *rope* getting cut and not the people...

Comment: @QuackE.Duck I'd post that as an answer if I were you.

Comment: Peter's answer is quite correct, but I would like to comment that your original misunderstanding wasn't actually that strange - many authorities hold a 'we do not negotiate with terrorists' position, at least officially, and it has been suggested that killing hostages deliberately would be an even better deterrent to hostage-taking.

Comment: "sending in troops" ***guns blazing*** - 'splitting the difference' : "*Figure we take out the terrorists. Lose twenty, twenty-five percent of the hostages, tops.* FBI Agent Johnson: *I can live with that*." - Compared to, "to talk until we figured out how to take [out *that one guy*, and *only* that one guy] with a gun" instead of destroying the building with C4 and covering everyone with broken glass.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think the two answerers have already covered it, but thanks!

Comment: Please don't add a new, albeit related, question after the original question has been answered.

Comment: You can post a new question, because that answer is definitely going to be different.

Comment: OK @Mari-LouA let me do it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Make someone free" means "liberate them". "Shoot them free" means liberate them by shooting, most likely by shooting those holding them captive.

"Free" here is the opposite of "captive", not the opposite of "costly".

The word order can appear odd. The actual (phrasal) verb is "shoot free", but we do not say "shoot free the hostages". There are several articles on *phrasal verbs*, for example this one at [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/common-phrasal-verbs/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I can not comprehend the structure that the direct object of *shoot* is *hostages*. Should it be *shoot for the hostages*?

Comment: @LernerZhang, the phrasal verb is *shoot free*. See my edited answer.

Comment: I believe "shoot free someone" or "shoot someone free"  is an idiom. phrasal verbs tend to have a verb followed by a preposition e.g. cut up, cut down, make of, run out, etc.

Comment: I don't think it's a phrasal verb to begin with. It's similar to headlinese, a shortened version of:  "They freed the hostages by shooting at the kidnappers" EDIT: The OP deleted their earlier comment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, The article I linked has examples (though not shoot free) such as "get back", e.g. He got his pencil back. It speaks of *separable* phrasal verbs.

Comment: I'm.not disputing the usefulness of the linked article, I don't believe "shoot free" is a phrasal verb, I've never seen it listed anywhere. I can't *come up with* any other situation/phrase  that would use this same construction.

Comment: What do you think is the gloss of *shoot* in this context (independently)? Can the phrasal verb apply in a context without involving a gun?

Comment: @LernerZhang I can't think of a context not involving guns.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I agree "shoot free" is not a common expression, and I didn't find it in any lists. On the other hand I didn't find any lists which claimed to contain all phrasal verbs. I don't believe it is "headlinese", as the context is not a headline. I immediately understood the sentence on reading it, understanding the expression as a phrasal verb. The structure is closely parallel to other phrasal verbs; "cut free" is similar and would, I think, be unremarkable. Analysing "shoot free" as a phrasal verb is, in my view, the most useful approach to understanding it.

Comment: @Peter - I am sure that the average native speaker can gather the meaning of a newly minted (for the occasion) 'phrasal verb' even if it is not on some list somewhere. One might _shoot them free_, or alternatively (as the article suggests _talk them free_. Good, pithy ways of concentrating on the core issue. If the authorities brought in a very loud opera singer and got her to bawl out arias from Carl Orff's _Carmina Burana_ to annoy the hostage takers beyond endurance, you could say the hostages were _sung free_, or maybe even _serenaded free_.

Comment: An analogy would be with "shoot dead" which is shoot + adjective dead; here "shoot free" means shoot so that they become free (not dead). English verbs often take an adjectival object complement as in "paint the wall black", "pick the bones clean", "mark the table reserved", "make the food tasty".

Comment: I would consider "shoot someone free" to be a witticism that playfully uses a somewhat forced turn of phrase (not common, requires reader to pause and parse it) to highlight the author's negative opinion of the Nixon administration's idea of hostage negotiation, which in the author's opinion is haphazard and badly formulated. The next sentence makes it clear that the author has a distaste for the liberators to focus on using guns to achieve their goal, and the phrasing of "shoot the hostages free" very much matches the contrast between the approaches that the author is trying to point out.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, your examples make sense. However, let's imagine that a man is undergoing torture by a group of terrorists and simply requests them to *shoot him free*. Is this usage idiomatic?

Comment: I might ask on ELU if your grammatical analysis–not the meaning–is correct/acceptable. If "shooting someone free" is a phrasal verb or multi-word verb then it *might* be listed as such by the OED. Unfortunately, I don't have access to it. @MichaelHarvey Who said the neologism  would be tricky for a native speaker to understand? Neologisms are created all the time but the vast vast majority are immediately forgotten. I personally don't believe this expression is a neologism but I'm hard pressed to find any practical use outside this specific case.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I would be surprised if even OED had it in a list. I couldn't find a match in Google ngrams. However I don't believe that invalidates my analysis, and I think if it was outrageously wrong it would have been picked up by one of the many people who contribute both to ELU and this forum. OTOH there may be better ways to analyse the expression, and it would be useful to see them

Comment: I have no qualms about the meaning of the phrase, it's spot on and explains it well, so many users are upvoting, and rightly so. I *do* have a problem with an answer that claims "shoot [someone] free" is a phrasal seeing as the OP has posted a new question calling it exactly that, a phrasal verb.  I'm prepared to be wrong about this, but unfortunately your arguments haven't convinced me I am.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There's a difference between "acts as a phrasal" and "is a phrase that you'll find in the dictionary." It works because there are so many established phrases of the pattern [verb] [something] [resultant condition], even if this phrase isn't a common one. "Cut them loose," "trim it short," "pull it tight," etc.

Comment: The main learning point here is what Andy says. It is that pattern that allows us to recognize ths one. Shoot dead is the most obvious comparison but then he correctly generalize it. However, it is also ironic as Flater points out above.

Answer (score 10):

One thing I haven't seen anyone mention: The meaning you suggested, of "without cost or at will," could have been created by *freely* instead of *free*. That would make all the difference:

> Shoot the hostages freely

In this phrase, "freely" is an adverb and just describes the way in which you shoot.

> Shoot the hostages free

In this version, "free" is a complement, part of a phrasal verb as noted elsewhere, and describes the condition of the hostages after shooting.

It should also be noted that this phrase isn't really common. It can be understood, mostly because it mirrors other more common scenarios in which you "[verb] [something] [condition]." A similar but more common usage might be, if you are entangled in a net or vines or similar, I might "cut you free." (But if I "cut you *freely*," the situation is very different!)

Comment: I was reading a 1950s electrical engineering textbook and came across a section about 'faults' (short-circuits or current leakage) between adjacent buried conductors and the author said 'in many cases they can be tricky to locate because they _burn themselves clear_'

Comment: To clarify, the insulation around two adjacent buried cables (which are at different potentials) could deteriorate enough to allow 'leakage' current to pass between them, generating heat, which further damages the insulation, making it even more conductive, until eventually the heat generated is enough to make the remaining degraded material catch fire and burn to ash which disperses.

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/346712/48180) is good and correct, but slightly misleading.

While the meaning is clear (freeing hostages via shooting), and @Peter correctly identifies that this acts as a phrasal verb, "shooting [something] free" is not a standard idiom.

The reason it is clear anyway is likely due to other matching constructions that *are* standard and idiomatic. For example, you can "cut [something] free," or "cut [something] loose," which both mean cutting the bonds that are holding something in place. The cutting leads to the result that [something] is free; you are not usually cutting the thing itself.

By just analyzing the words, you could easily read "shoot the hostages free" as "shoot the hostages, so they are 'free'." That's not an impossible meaning, but it is also not the natural meaning. In the same way, "[someone] went to sleep" does not naturally indicate that someone died, even though you do sometimes see sleep used as a euphemism for death.